# iOS: Firebase: Database lives in a different region. Where to put the link?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and I am currently making my first ever Firebase app. (Xcode SwiftUI iOS 15.0)
I have this problem. When I want to save messages to my Realtime Database, I get this error:

> Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server.
> Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Database lives in a different
> region. Please change your database URL to
> "My Firebase URL"

(My database is already linked to this URL)

On other posts I saw this soloution:

```
let ref = Database.database(url: "My Firebase URL")
```

Where do I have to put this line of code?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put that code wherever you are creating a reference to data from Firebase.

If you look at this code from step 3 of the Firebase documentation on [setting up a connection to the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start#set_up):

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

ref = Database.database().reference()
```

This syntax creates a reference to the database as it is defined in your `GoogleService-Info.plist` file.

Since you want to specify the URL in your code, you'd do:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

ref = Database.database("your database URL").reference()
```

And then use `ref` everywhere else to [read and write data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write).

---

You can alternatively also download an updated `GoogleService-Info.plist` file from the Firebase console, and replace the one in your Xcode project with it. In that case the SDK will pick up the URL from the updated file.